# sql unordered output (result)

Tags: sql, oracle10g, unordered

I am using The **Oracle Database 10g Express Edition**. I just want to know how to fix this problem. I am having a big issue while I want to see information, I mean the output of queries. Just look how untidy, unordered is the output. Thanks! [image: As you can see in the photo]

Comment: what database engine are you connecting to? Mysql? Postgres? Oracle? Something else?

Comment: This is **Oracle databse 10g Express Edition**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL*Plus, you have some control over formatting via SQL*Plus specific commands. For example:

```
SET PAGESIZE 9999
SET LINESIZE 120
COL equipo_local FORMAT A12
```

See the SQL*Plus Reference manual for more SQL*Plus commands.

```
SET HEADING OFF
SET TRIMSPOOL ON
```

etc.

If you want rows returned in a particular sequence, add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query.

Comment: @Abdullah - then you will see that you need to issue the same commands every time you start a new session. To save all that work, read in the SQL\*Plus manual about saving these commands in a `login.sql` file, which is read right away each time you start a session.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to spencer's advice, especially `SET LINESIZE 120` (which means you will display 120 characters per line in the output), study the SQL*Plus command `COLUMN` - especially the `FORMAT` option. For example, SQL*Plus is formatting `EQUIPO_LOCAL` at about 25 characters (eyeball estimate); if you issue the command `COLUMN EQUIPO_LOCAL a14` the column will be just 14 characters making room for more columns (the hope is to fit all columns in the total 120 characters, so each row of the output is shown in one line of text on screen).

Spend a couple of hours reading through the user's manual for SQL*Plus, you will learn a lot of helpful things. Keep in mind, too, that SQL*Plus is a separate program, with its own commands/language; SQL*Plus commands are NOT SQL statements! (That is often confusing.)

Comment: Good point, making the distinction of commands specific to the SQL\*Plus client e.g. `SET` and `COL` which are processed by the SQL\*Plus client, and are *not* sent to the Oracle server as SQL statements. +10